# Machine specific slow read_excel read times

Tags: r, readxl

I'm getting really slow read times using `read_excel` on a particular machine with a particular xlsm file. Reading the same xlsm file across 2 different machines I get read times of 72 seconds versus 0.2 seconds. Where the slower machine actually has more computational power.

Both machines are Windows and I'm using `readxl` package version 1.1.0 on both machines. I've tried using package v1.2.0 on the slower machine and the same problem persists.

I had been reading this xlsm file into R for the last 2 years+ without any problems. I had been regularly running a set of macros on the excel file over those 2 years. Now, however, when I run those same macros and save the file, the slower machine now take 70s instead of <1s to read it into R. If I ask the slower machine to read older versions of the xlsm file it has no problems. The file is approximately 15MB. It doesn't matter which tab of the xlsm file I ask `read_excel` to read, the time is still about 70 seconds.

I've updated R (v3.5.2) and ensured all the `readxl` package dependencies are up to date too. I'm at a loss as to what else to try, any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: A shot in the dark: maybe one of the alternatives `openxlsx::read_xlsx` or `openxlsx::loadWorkbook` offer better performance (I seem to recall reading `.xlsm;.xlsx;.xlsb` files with `openxlsx`, only `.xls` was not supported as far as I know)

Comment: what does `readxl::excel_format()`  say?

Comment: @Wimpel on both machines 'xlsx'.

Comment: thanks @nate.edwinton. Using `openxlsx::read.xlsx` I get 9 seconds read time on slower machine and 1.7 seconds on faster machine.

Comment: Does opening the file in Excel (or LibreOffice's Calc) demonstrate the same difference in opening times?

Comment: @r2evans, on the slower machine it takes 46 seconds to open, on the faster machine 21 seconds.

Comment: That is perplexing, I was thinking it might be related to something related to Windows. (This might still be the case, but is less obvious now to me.)

Comment: @r2evans I could try a complete reinstall of windows, I have already tried a re-install of MSOffice.

Comment: I have no reason (other than curiosity) to think that that would help in this situation. Then again, I can't think of anything else. Sorry, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: When I tested my below solution it worked once and then never again after that.

New solution: The only real solution I can find is reverting to an older version of readxl.

1) Install RTools 3.5 - https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

2) Install devtools package - `install.packages("devtools")`

3) Install readxl version 1.2.0 - `devtools::install_version("readxl", "1.2.0")`

Incorrect solution:

> A similar thing has been happening to me and I recently managed to
>   "fix" it by **deleting all of the workbook/worksheet 'names' in the
>   excel file** before trying to load it in with readxl.
>
> Some background: People had added a bunch of junk names referencing
>   external connections and I'm wondering if readxl was trying to resolve
>   these before loading in the data causing it to hang. I don't know why
>   it only hangs on my current computer while the same file won't hang
>   when loading on another computer.

Comment: Thanks for you input Anthony, what do you mean by 'junk names'?

Comment: In excel if you go to Formulas -> Name Manager you will see a list of all the names that exist in your workbook. There were many that were #REF errors or just no longer being used for anything.